# Convert 1D numpy.array([]) to numpy.array([[]])

Tags: python, numpy

Im calculating results for each rows in 2D-array.

```
import numpy as np
xyz = np.array([[1, 2, 100],[2, 5, 100]])
resultcolumn1 = (xyz[:,0]+xyz[:,1])*xyz[:,2]
>>array([300, 700])
>>type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

But when I'm trying to add this resultvector to rest of the 2D-array as a column

```
print np.concatenate((xyz, resultcolumn1.T), axis=1)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions.

Declaring the same vector with double brackets. Works:

```
resultcolumn2=np.array([[300, 700]])
>>>array([[300, 700]])
>>><type 'numpy.ndarray'>
np.concatenate((xyz, resultcolumn2.T), axis=1)
>>>[[  1   2 100 300]
    [  2   5 100 700]]
```

How do I change resultcolumn1 to match resultcolumn2? Also could this process be done in better fashion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reshape list to ndim array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432378/python-reshape-list-to-ndim-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an extra dimension:

```
>>> np.concatenate((xyz, resultcolumn1.T[..., None]), axis=1)
array([[  1,   2, 100, 300],
       [  2,   5, 100, 700]])
```

Also, note that for a 1d array, `.T` (i.e. transpose) does nothing so you can simply drop it:

```
>>> np.concatenate((xyz, resultcolumn1[..., None]), axis=1)
array([[  1,   2, 100, 300],
       [  2,   5, 100, 700]])
```

Comment: If `resultcolumn1` is 1d, the `.T` does nothing.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah yes, adding that to the answer. Thanks.