# Taking n elements at a time from 1d list and add them to 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a list making up data, and I'd like to take 4 elements at a time from this list and put them in a 2d list where each 4-element increment is a new row of said list.

My first attempts involve input to 1d list:
`list.append(input("Enter data type 1:")) list.append(input("Enter data type 2:")) etc.`
and then I've tried to loop the list and to "switch" rows once the index reaches 4.

```
for x in range(n * 4):
    for idx, y in enumerate(list):
        if idx % 4 == 0:
            x = x + 1
            list[y] = result[x][y]
```

where I've initialised result according to the following:
and

> ran = int(len(list)/4)

```
result=[[0 for x in range(ran)] for j in range(n)]
```

I've also attempted to ascribe a temporary empty list that will append to an initialised 2D list.
`

```
row.append(list)
     
result=[[x for x in row] for j in range(n + 1)]
#result[n]=row
print(result)
n = n + 1
row.clear()
list.clear()
```

so that each new loop starts with an empty row, takes input from user and copies it.
I'm at a loss for how to make result save the first entry and not be redefined at second,third,fourth entries.

Comment: Suggestion: do not use `list` as a variable name, since you are starting out it is better not to use languages's keywords as variables/constants name.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not, just put it in for clarity! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432378/python-reshape-list-to-ndim-array) is probably what you need. With np.reshape() you can just have your list filled with all the values you need and do the reshaping after in a single step.

Comment: Yes alright but I'm refraining from using numpy at all..

Comment: @StudentNumberThreeXPlusOne why that? numpy is super useful